# Some property doesn't work from JSON parsing

Tags: c#, json, xaml

I have an Windows 8 app that read from website as Json and I made the class that contains property needed for parsing the Json file.
The problem is when I binding the data to TextBlocks some values show's up and some don't even when I use the Url in the browser it's have info and not null!

```
 public class Rootobject 
{
    public Player player { get; set; }
    public Stats stats { get; set; }
    public Dogtags dogtags { get; set; }
    public Weapon[] weapons { get; set; }
    public Kititem[] kititems { get; set; }
    public Vehicle[] vehicles { get; set; }
    public Vehiclecategory[] vehicleCategory { get; set; }
    public Award[] awards { get; set; }
}

public class Player
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string game { get; set; }
    public string plat { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string tag { get; set; }
    public long dateCheck { get; set; }
    public long dateUpdate { get; set; }
    public long dateCreate { get; set; }
    public object lastDay { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public object countryName { get; set; }
    public Rank rank { get; set; }
    public int score { get; set; }
    public int timePlayed { get; set; }
    public string uId { get; set; }
    public string uName { get; set; }
    public string uGava { get; set; }
    public long udCreate { get; set; }
    public string blPlayer { get; set; }
    public string blUser { get; set; }
    public bool editable { get; set; }
    public bool viewable { get; set; }
    public bool adminable { get; set; }
    public bool linked { get; set; }
}
```

and The XAML is:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="playerTemp">
        <Grid Width="400" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
            <StackPanel >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Name:"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=player.name}"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Platform:"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=player.plat}"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Country:"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=player.countryName}" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Date Create:"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=player.lastDay}"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Last Update:"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=player.dateUpdate}"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Time Played:"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=player.timeplayed}"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Score:"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=player.score}" />
                </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>


<GridView Name="myGridView" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource nameTemp}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Width="800"/>
```

And the parsing code is:

```
private ObservableCollection<Rootobject> root= new ObservableCollection<Rootobject>();

        public Details()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
            this.navigationHelper.LoadState += navigationHelper_LoadState;
            this.navigationHelper.SaveState += navigationHelper_SaveState;

            myGridView.ItemsSource = root;

        }

private async Task<Root> DoIT()
        {
            string theUrl = "www.SomeUrl.com";
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(theUrl);
            using (Stream stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(uri))
            {
                DataContractJsonSerializer serial = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Rootobject));
                Rootobject root = (Rootobject)serial.ReadObject(stream);
                var obj = root;
                return obj;
            }
        }  

private async void btnDoIT_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Root data = await DoIT();
            root.Add(data);
        }
```

The problem is all values in the TextBlocks works good except Value3 and Value6 and when I use the url in browser it gets:

```
{"player":{"id":860573104,"game":"bf4","plat":"pc","name":"MedoOmar2011","tag":"MAAO","dateCheck":1386060441862,"dateUpdate":1386060441862,"dateCreate":1385683079202,"lastDay":"20131128","country":"","countryName":null,"rank":{"nr":7,"imgLarge":"bf4/ranks/r7.png","img":"r7","name":"Lance Corporal II","needed":91000,"next":{"nr":8,"img":"r8","name":"Lance Corporal III","needed":115000,"curr":107666,"relNeeded":24000,"relCurr":16666,"relProg":69.44166666666666}},"score":107666,"timePlayed":21172,"
```

I can't show platand timePlay.

Comment: First problem: your properties all start with `v` whereas your JSON and binding values start with `V`. I'm surprised the binding works at all.

Comment: I edited the propertys name to make it simple it's not the exactly names of propertys.

Comment: That's unhelpful. You should show a short but complete program which is representative of your code, and which demonstrates the same problem. Otherwise we won't know which errors are due to your inaccurate editing and which errors are really the ones you're trying to solve.

Comment: Is the problem in your JSON parsing, or in your XAML bindings? You know better than we do; you've got the code, and a debugger. You'll get a good answer much sooner if readers don't have to wade through irrelevant details.

Comment: The JSON parsing is automated and every the app work fine without bugs but also with couple of empty fields.

Comment: @MedoOmar: You haven't added the full code, and we don't even need your *original* code - we just need a short but complete program that will demonstrate the problem.

Comment: What should I add? I post all the code that involved in the problem I have there is nothing more to add except some buttons and text not relative to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

At a quick glance, the values at the bottom include "Value16", which I assume should be Value6, and the value assigned to it is a string value that is far too large to fit in an int.

Comment: Thanks,the last value is wrong. I edited it with the right value.

Comment: You've now got a floating point number (float, decimal etc) that you're trying to assign to an int.

Comment: @MedoOmar could be a problem of float formating (69.44 vs. 69,44)

Comment: If this is directly copied then Jon Skeet may have been right earlier, as you have timePlayed as the variable, but referenced as player.timeplayed. Try changing that and see if that works.